# Why is the conditional probability of events following a Poisson process normally distributed?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, poisson-process

Suppose that radioactive particles hit a surface according to a Poisson process of rate $\lambda = 20$ per hour.  A total of $100$ particles arrived in the first $10$ hours. Conditional on this, I find the probability that $n(n ≤ 100)$ arrived the first $4$ hours.

The answer is:

\begin{align}
P(X(4)=n|X(10) = 100) &= \frac{P(X(4)=n,X(10) = 100)}{P(X(10) = 100)} \\
&= \frac{P(X(4)=n,X(10)-X(4) = 100-n)}{P(X(10) = 100)} \\
&= \frac{P(X(4)=n)\cdot P(X(10)-X(4) = 100-n)}{P(X(10) = 100)} \\
&= {100\choose n}\left(\frac{4}{6}\right)^n\left(\frac{6}{10}\right)^{100}
\end{align}

Now, if plot this for values $n=0$ to $n=100$, I get the following graph:

[image]

Is there a reason for this? I know that the Poisson Distribution can be approximated by a normal distribution, but is there a reason this conditional process is as well?

Comment: This conditional process is just a binomial process with $n=100$ and $p=\frac{2}{5}$.

Comment: To answer the question in the title: They are not (normally distributed), being binomial, but what your plot shows is the phenomenon that binomial distributions of parameter $(N,p)$ (when $N$, $p$ and $1-p$ are not too small) are well approximated (once properly renormalized) by normal distributions. This follows from (refinements of) the *central limit theorem*. In your case, $N=100$ and $p=\frac4{10}$ hence the fit is excellent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the conditional distribution is not normal, but binomial with $n=100$ and $p=\frac 4{10}$. 
Maybe this is less surprising if you know the Poisson-limit theorem:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_limit_theorem

For a moment, think of the Poisson distribution as a Binomial distribution: then each of the 100 particles (which arrived upon time 10) have an equal chance of arriving at any of the times $1,2,\dots,10$. Then the expression for the conditional probability is less surprising.

Hope that this was helpful.

Comment: The question is why this distribution is nearly normal. See my comment on main.